# Maximum input length exceeded of java program in linux shell

Tags: java, linux, shell

I've created a wonderfully working program that encrypts the text a person enters with a keyword of their choice. The program can decrypt the encrypted message/text by going in decrypt mode and entering the correct key.
Now my problem is that when I enter a text in the Linux shell that's longer than approximately 5000 characters, it doesn't process all the text. I used [this](https://germantestdrive.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/langer-test-text/) German dummy text that's 15954 characters long. If I enter the text in the Linux shell It cuts off my text at about 4025 characters. On the other hand, if I execute the program in IntelliJ everything works like a charm. If you need the code I got on git [here](https://github.com/LJJW/Vigenere-Cipher.git).
Thanks in advance. I appreciate the help.

My Start class that starts everything

```
public class Start
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a message? [d/e]\n>");
        char de = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        boolean _Encrypt = true;

        if (de == 'd')
            _Encrypt = false;
        else if (de == 'e')
            ;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Non valid input. Please try again later.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        char[] text = ch.wagner.root.viginere.Input.getText("Text:\n>");

        char[] key = ch.wagner.root.viginere.Input.getKey("Key:\n>");

        if (_Encrypt)
        {
            System.out.println(ch.wagner.root.viginere.Process.encrypt(text, key));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(ch.wagner.root.viginere.Process.decrypt(text, key));
        }
    }
}
```

My Input class

```
public class Input
{
    public static char[] getText (String requestMessage)
    {
        boolean _AllowedToContinue = false;

        char[] text = null;
        while (!_AllowedToContinue)
        {
            System.out.print(requestMessage);
            text = ch.wagner.root.viginere.Input.getCharArray();

            if (!Input.inputValid(new String(text), "[^`^]+$"))
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            else
                _AllowedToContinue = true;
        }

//      System.err.println(new String(text).length());
//      Created this to check the length of the String after input

        return text;
    }

    public static char[] getKey (String requestMessage)
    {
        boolean _AllowedToContinue = false;

        char[] key = null;
        while (!_AllowedToContinue)
        {
            System.out.print(requestMessage);
            key = ch.wagner.root.viginere.Input.getCharArray();

            if (!Input.inputValid(new String(key), "^[A-Za-z]+$"))
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            else
                _AllowedToContinue = true;
        }

        return key;
    }

    private static boolean inputValid (String input, String regex)
    {
        boolean returnValue = true;

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        if (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
            returnValue = false;
        }

        return  returnValue;
    }

    private static String getString ()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    private static char[] getCharArray ()
    {
        return getString().toCharArray();
    }
}
```

The Process class that encrypts/decrypts the text

```
public class Process
{
    public static String decrypt(char[] text, char[] key)
    {
        int[] shift = new int[key.length];

        key = new String(key).toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < shift.length; i++)
            shift[i] = key[i] - 65;

        int ii = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        {
            if (ii == shift.length)
                ii = 0;

            if (Character.isLetter(text[i]))
            {
                if (((((text[i] - 65) - shift[ii]) % 26) + 65) < 65)
                    text[i] = (char) (((((text[i] - 65) - shift[ii]) % 26) + 65) + 26);
                else
                    text[i] = (char) ((((text[i] - 65) - shift[ii]) % 26) + 65);
            }
            ii++;
        }

        return new String(text);
    }

    public static String encrypt(char[] text, char[] key)
    {
        int[] shift = new int[key.length];

        key = new String(key).toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < shift.length; i++)
        {
            shift[i] = key[i] - 65;
        }

        text = new String(text).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9|/()*]+", "").toCharArray();

        int ii = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        {
            if (ii == shift.length)
                ii = 0;

            text[i] = Character.toUpperCase(text[i]);

            if (Character.isLetter(text[i]))
                text[i] = (char)((((text[i] - 65) + shift[ii]) % 26) + 65);
            ii++;
        }

        return new String(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a shell problem. How exactly do you get the input into your Java program? What error message do you get? Piping a file should not fail, no matter how big it is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you wrote is a crucial piece of information in order to come up with a good answer. Linking to your Github project is not an ideal way to provide that information. One reason is that your project is volatile, you'll probably change the code or even might decide to move it somewhere else entirely. Then, this Q&A would be rendered useless for posterity. Instead, please create a so called [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it, properly formatted, directly in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get any error message, it's that when I enter a long text to encrypt, the text that results from all that is way too short to be the encrypted variant of the text I entered. Usually, it should be about 20% shorter due to all spaces, commas and other special characters are stripped to ensure more security. When I try entering a text that's 15l characters long, it comes out about 3500 characters long although it should be about 12900 characters long.

Comment: Which text doesn't it process? It looks like it will only process the last line.

Comment: What you should do to improve this question, is just paste your input class, and show that it doesn't take in all of the characters. From the looks of it, it appears fundamentally broken to me. It is only going to return the last line, if your text has any line breaks in it. Also the loop would never end, unless you have invalid text.

Comment: At some point, it stops reading the string from the console. Like I input a String that's 15000 characters long and in the Linux shell it only reads about 4000 characters, whereas in the IntelliJ console it reads all 15000 characters

Comment: You should really be able to reduce this problem down to getting input. We don't need to know about your encryption/decryption schemes. As it is, your getText is fundamentally broken, but that might not be your problem, since you say it works in intellij. You might need to modify a configuration of your terminal to have a longer buffer.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal#131274